# Cocoa - AutoLayout - get frame size width in 10.9

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, cgrect

I would like to know the `frame` of an `NSView` that has been displayed using AutoLayout (ie, constraints). I know how to do this in 10.10 by using `-(void)viewDidLayout` in `NSViewController`, but this method is only available in 10.10. Is there another way to get the frame of a view prior to 10.10? Note, that before `viewDidLayout`, the frame is not set, as the view has not been placed yet.

Comment: viewDidMoveToWindow might be called after auto layout, but I haven't tested myself

Comment: @Volker - thanks for the suggestion - I will try it out tonight and report back.

Comment: @Volker unfortunately `viewDidMoveToWindow` is only available in 10.10 "Available in OS X v10.0 and later." - nice try though :)

Comment: viewDidMoveToWindow is available since 10.0 -> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/viewDidMoveToWindow but not within NSViewController but within NSView -> please reread what you copy&pasted in your comment ;)

Comment: @Volker - sorry only saw your comment now. Ha ha ha - you are totally right : D